# Declaring functions inside initComponent Ext JS4

Tags: javascript, function, scope, extjs4, declare

Im working on a project using Ext JS4. In some of our classes we are declaring functions inside the initComponent function which may then be set as handlers to a control. I will include an example of this below. Ignore most of what is in the class, the key details are the fact that the Handlers are declared within initComponent and set as handlers to the buttons.

Now, this actually WORKS - the qestion here is WHY this works. I'm fairly new to JavaScript, but I thought that any vars or functions declared within a function were destroyed once that function had completed. Is this incorrect? I appreciate that there may be a better coding style to this, but I would really like to get my head around this before I consider changing loads of classes. The class is as follows... Some comments identify the key areas.

```
Ext.onReady(function () { 
    Ext.application({ 

        name: 'Form2', 
        thisForm: {}, 

        launch: function() { 
            thisForm = Ext.create('Form2', {});
        }
    });
});

Ext.define('Form2', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    layout:'border',

    config: {
        controlManager: {},
        formVariables:  {},
        dataHelper:     {}
    },

    constructor: function () {
        var me = this;

        ...
        ...

        // Initialize the form - I know, this might not be the be best coding style here.
        me.initComponent();
    },

    initComponent: function() {

    Ext.QuickTips.init(); 

    var ButtonControl1 = this.controlManager.createButton('ButtonControl1');

    var ButtonControl2 = this.controlManager.createButton('ButtonControl2');

    ...
    ... 

    // Handler for Btton1 - **I'm not using the var keyword in this declaration**
    function Handler1() { 
        alert('This Works!');
    };

    // Handler for Btton2 - **I'm using the var keyword in this example**
    var Handler2 = function () {
        alert('This Works also!');
    }; 

    // THIS IS THE KEY PART OF THIS QUESTION - even though the handler functions are declared
    // locally (above), clicking the buttons will still execute these. Do the functions
    // still exist by chance, and will be garbage collected at some later time, or are they
    // actually quaranteed to be there. I'm confused!

    ButtonControl1.onClickEventHandler = function () {Handler1();};

    ButtonControl2.onClickEventHandler = function () {Handler2();};

    // Don't need to worry about this part.

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', { 
        layout:'border', 
        style: { position:'relative' }, 
        defaults: { 
            collapsible: true, 
            split: true, 
            bodyStyle: 'padding:0px' 
        }, 
             items: [ 
                 { 
                       collapsible: false, 
                 split: false, 
                     region: 'north', 
                     height: 50, 
                     margins: '0 2 0 2', 
                     bbar: '', 
                     items: [  ] 
                 }, 
                 { 
                     collapsible: false, 
                     split: false, 
                     region:'west', 
                     margins: '0 0 0 0', 
                     cmargins: '0 2 0 2', 
                     width: 0, 
                     lbar: [  ] 
                 }, 
                 { 
                     collapsible: false, 
                     region:'center', 
                     margins: '0 2 0 2', 
                     layout: { 
                         align: 'stretch', 
                         type: 'hbox' 
                     }, 
                     items: [ 
                         { 
                             xtype: 'form', 
                             fileUpload: true, 
                             layout: { 
                                 align: 'stretch', 
                                 type: 'vbox' 
                             }, 
                             flex: 1, 
                             items: [ 
                             { 
                                 xtype: 'container', 
                                 height: 550, 
                                 layout: { 
                                     align: 'stretch', 
                                     type: 'hbox' 
                                 }, 
                                 items: [ 
                                 { 
                                     xtype: 'container', 
                                     width: 570, 
                                     layout: 'vbox', 
                                     padding: '5 0 0 0', 
                                     style:'background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);', 
                                     items: [ 
                                         ButtonControl1, ButtonControl2
                                     ] 
                                 }
                                 ] 
                             } 
                             ] 
                         } 
                     ] 
                 } 
             ] 
         }); 
     } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For primitive variables (like string or int), when the function finished all its local variables are distroyed.

For non-primitive variables, the object created locally (such as array or Ext object) will not be distroyed while there is any other object references to it.

In your example ButtonControl1 and ButtonControl2 are declared outside initComponent.

Inside initComponent function, onClickEventHandler is a handler references to Handler1 and Handler2 functions. 
When initComponent run finishes, because ButtonControl1 and ButtonControl2 are not in the scope of initComponent (but in the scope of onReady function), they remain to be alive and therefore also all of the objects they are reference to.

```
var ButtonControl1  = ....; // this global variable object
var ButtonControl2  = ....; // this global variable object

initComponent: function() {

    function Handler1() { 
      ...
    };

    var Handler2 = function () {
      ...
    }; 

    // ButtonControl1 and ButtonControl2 are declared outside of initComponent. 
    // Unless these variables will be distroyed, they keep onClickEventHandler references to Handler1 and Handler2 objects and therefore these objects will alive outside the scope of initComponent. 
    ButtonControl1.onClickEventHandler = function () {Handler1();};
    ButtonControl2.onClickEventHandler = function () {Handler2();};

}
```

Consider the last function in the scope of onReady is initComponent (i.e. there is no any other event handler defined). 
So why all these objects will remain be alive after initComponent finishes?

The answer is created 'Ext.container.Viewport' object, which is rendered to document's page and therefore all attached objects and reference objects are alive as well.